# Can someone help me in identifying this font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have scouted the internet looking for this font in the image below. I have searched through [www.myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com), [whatthefont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) and other font identifier websites but no head way. Can someone please help me out? Thank you.

[image: Word Saying Empire]

Answer (score 1):

That's **[Cinzel Decorative](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cinzel+Decorative?preview.text=EMPIRE&preview.text_type=custom)** font by [Natanael Gama](https://www.behance.net/ndiscovered). Typed in all upper case at a weight of about `700` at a size of about 82px but from the looks of it, the Kerning on the <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> has been reduced by the designer so they almost touch.

Here are more font identifiers, you can use [`FontSquirrel`](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator?token=9t1a31rm69bz2isk), Myfonts' [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), Fontspring's [FONT MATCHERTER](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator), whatfontis.com among others. Personally `FontSquirrel's` Macherator almost gives me about 70% accuracy on most fonts I get to look up.

Comment: Thank you very much you just saved a life, that is very accurate

Comment: Glad it was helpful @EmmanuelOkezieOgbonna, you can mark it as an answer then. :)